# HTML5/javascript X11 server?

Tags: javascript, linux, html, x11

We have an application which consumes a large amount of data. Currently a desktop app, but we would like to deliver it via the browser.

It doesn't make sense to me to create a web app where we need to transfer a ll the data used for the visualizations.

We're looking at RDP and some products out there that provide RDP access via a fully javascript client. They seem to work well with our app, but I've been thinking about what it would take to move off Windows.

Switching the front end so that it could run under Linux would not be trivial, but not impossible, so the main stumbling block would be delivery.

I was wondering if there are any X11 javascript servers out there, but have not found any leads.

Comment: Which toolkit is your desktop application coded in (Qt, GTK, something else?)?

Comment: Right now it's a Windows application written in C++ using WTL, but we're not against a rewrite using Qt or GTK. How does that make a difference?

Comment: @bpeikes what did you end up using? I'm also looking to deliver a single application via JS in a browser.

Answer (score 13):

Use [xpra's builtin html5 client](https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra-html5), it supports any application you can run on an X11 desktop.

Comment: (avoid the Debian and Ubuntu packages, which are missing the html5 client - use the official xpra.org packages instead)

Comment: Well, as far as I understand it xpra'S html5 client does not implement X11 but only the xpra protocol. So you need to run the xpra server component on the other side as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an HTML5 VNC viewer like https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC coupled with a VNC server like [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/)

Comment: The problem with VNC is that it's desktop based as far as I can tell. We're looking for something more like RDP Remote App, or X11 which allows a single application to be displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, recent [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) has been ported to HTML5+Javascript in [Gtk Broadway](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/gtk-broadway.html)

And you could make your application a web application, for instance by using [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), or by making it an HTTP server thru specialized HTTP server libraries like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) etc.

By using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) techniques (e.g. thru [jquery](http://jquery.com/)) your application won't transmit all the display data to the browser at once (but only incrementally and only the actually shown data).

You might also consider [fastcgi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastcgi) as a way to connect your application to some web server.

Comment: Took a look at GTK, looks interesting, but it doesn't seem stable enough nor does it seem like it's meant to be used as an enterprise solution.
I'm not sure how Wt, libonion or libmicorhttpd answers my question. I'm not looking to run my application as a web server.

Comment: GTK itself is used for Gnome. I'm surprised you call it not stable enough. Many Linux desktops are GTK based!

Comment: I'm not saying that GTK is not stable. The HTML5 support in Broadway is fairly new. It also doesn't have a framework for starting the application via the web or running multiple instances of the same application as a single server (as far as I know).

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-broadway.html has an explanation of how to do it.  Basically set up a start page that queries your server, then the server determines the next available port, runs the command and redirects the client to the appropriate port (each network device can host over 50k clients).

Answer (score 3):

I know two, both at very infancy:

https://github.com/GothAck/javascript-x-server

and

https://github.com/ttaubert/x-server-js

Both need simple tcp-to-websockets proxy in front, but all X11 logic happen inside web page and all x11 objects exist and interact within browser (so it's not just remote framebuffer but real server)

Comment: Neither of these have been worked on. I was looking for a product or open source project that's being used in a production environment.

Comment: Just checked, both of these seem to be abandoned: `javascript-x-server` was last updated 2 years ago, `x-server-js` 4 years ago :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can ever run full Linux distribution in Web Browser, but that's require to run x86/ARM emulator and GNU/Linux inside it. It provides X server with possible web connection too.

Answer (score 0):

For very simple applications you can use libgreattao toolkit and tao-network-client to connect to it. I'm the author of both project. The API isn't yet frozen, but it rather behaves stable. You can read about it here:
https://nintyfan.wordpress.com/2015/04/30/server-buildin-into-libgreattao-and-tao-network-client/

It can provide some problems with applications with a lot of data, because all elements must be send to client, when it were created, but instead we don't send full graphics(only icons is send) and user interface could be changed quickly. It also don't support mouse enter/leave/move events.

I must tell: do not download tarbar, but download version from svn.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the easiest approach for you is to get xrdp, which is an RDP-server for X. Then you would use your RDP client to connect to it. I think Nomachine NX supports html directly now, but I'm not sure. There was talk of an html X2go-client, but I don't know anything about that either.